# $(x^2+y^4)f(x,y)+f^3(x,y)=1 \implies f\in C^1(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ be open and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $$(x^2+y^4)f(x,y)+f^3(x,y)=1$$ for each $(x,y)\in \Omega$. Prove that $f\in C^1(\Omega)$.

If is assumed that $f$ is differentiable, easily we get that the partials derivatives are continuous in $\Omega$, so $f\in C^1(\Omega)$. But I don't know how to prove that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: **Hint** Use Cardano's formulas for the third degree equation.

Comment: @Gribouillis thank you for the comment and the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2,$ there is a unique $z\in \mathbb R$ such that

$$\tag 1 (x^2+y^4)z + z^3 = 1.$$

That's because for each fixed $a\ge 0,$ the function $t\to at+t^3$ is a bijection of $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R.$ Thus $(1)$ defines $z$ as a function of $(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2.$ Let's call this function $g(x,y).$

Set $h(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^4)z + z^3.$ Note that

$$\tag 2\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}(x,y,z) = x^2+y^4+ 3z^2.$$

This is nonzero except at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0).$ Since $(0,0,0)$ doesn't solve $(1),$ we have $(2)$ non-zero at every point of the surface given by $(1).$ Because $h$ is $C^1,$ the implicit function theorem shows $g(x,y)$ is locally $C^1,$ hence globally $C^1.$ Since $f(x,y) = g(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\in \Omega$ by uniqueness, we have $f\in C^1(\Omega)$ as deisred. (It appears that $f\in C^\infty(\Omega )$ actually.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By [Cardano's formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula)
one has

$$f \left(x , y\right) = g \left(x , y\right)-\frac{{x}^{2}+{y}^{4}}{3 g \left(x , y\right)}$$

with

$$g \left(x , y\right) = \sqrt[\large{3}]{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{{\left({x}^{2}+{y}^{4}\right)}^{3}}{27}}}$$

It follows that $f \in  {\mathscr{C}}^{\infty } \left({\Omega}\right)$

Comment: By Cardano's formula $f(x,y)$ is supposed to be sum of cubic roots? I'dont understand the final expression of $f$.

Comment: It is true, if $h(x, y)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}-\cdots}$ is the other cubic root, then one has $g h = -\frac{x^2+ y^4}{3}$. This is the condition that allows one to choose the correct cubic root when one works with complex numbers. It is easier to write the solution as above because it is obvious that it is smooth.